# javascript compare all attributes of an object with other object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have two objects `A`

```
var A = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: {
        0: {
            e: 4,
            f: 5
        },
        1: {
            g: 6
        }
    }
};

var B = {
    a: 1,
    b: 9,
    c: 3,
    d: {
        0: {
            e: 4,
            f: 8
        }
    }
};
```

I want to compare all attributes in B with corresponding attributes in A, if present. Return if their values doesn't match.

so I want to return

```
   b: 9,
    d:{
       0: {
          f: 8
       }
    }
```

Is there a simple soluton for this in lodash way?

EDIT : I tried Object.keys for A and B, did a intersection and then compare each key value. Its failing when I have nested attributes.

Comment: Please post the code you already used so other people can try to help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic function that uses lodash to detect changes in simple nested objects and arrays.  It is by no means comprehensive, but it works well for simple changesets.

```
function changes (a, b) {
  if (_.isEqual(a, b)) {
    return;
  } else {
    if (_.isArray(a) && _.isArray(b)) {
      return _.reduce(b, function(array, value, index) {
        value = changes(a[index], value);
        if (!_.isUndefined(value)) {
          array[index] = value;
        }
        return array;
      }, []);
    } else if (_.isObject(a) && _.isObject(b)) {
      return _.reduce(b, function(object, value, key) {
        value = changes(a[key], value);
        if (!_.isUndefined(value)) {
          object[key] = value;
        }
        return object;
      }, {});
    } else {
      return b;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is an example of it in action: http://plnkr.co/edit/drMyGDAh2XP0925pBi8X?p=preview